# Colocar filtro de validación en producto

Tags: php, validación, woocommerce

Estoy construyendo una web con woocommerce instale un plugin llamado tm opction extra, pero no me permite validar los campos adicionales en la página producto antes de agregarlo al proceso de pago, ahora bien realice un código en php que puse en el archivo `funtion.php` de mi tema y realizo la comprobación que necesitaba,  ahora el problema que me ocurre es que dicha validación se esta cargando en todos los demás productos, y quisiera poder delimitarlo a un producto especifico de woocommerce, y no se como hacerlo mi código es algo parecido a esto, como puede verse es un filtro general para todos los productos.

```
function filtrodeproducto_add_to_cart_validation($passed, $product_id, $qty){
/* primer campo validados con los demas 
 */
    if( isset(  $_POST['tmcp_textfield_0'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST['tmcp_textfield_0'] ) ==  $_POST['tmcp_textfield_1'] ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s Utilice numeros diferentes para cada caso.', 'filtrodeproducto-plugin-textdomain' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
        return false;

    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filtrodeproducto_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
```

Campos para validar

`tmcp_textfield_0`  este es el campo que estoy intentando validar con este otro `tmcp_textfield_1` pero todos los demás productos tienen campos llamados de la misma manera y no puedo modificarlos por el plugin

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Tardes logre resolver y fue mas facil de lo que pensaba, solo tendrian que colocar luego de

```
function filtrodeproducto_add_to_cart_validation($passed, $product_id, $qty){
/* primer campo validados con los demas
```

if(  $product_id== 4239 )

ya que la misma función esta trayendo el id del producto y asi delimitaria la funcion solo para el producto que quiero validar. Fue muy tonto no darme cuenta antes de esto.